# Numpy / Python - ValueError: could not assign tuple of length 6 to structure with 3 fields

Tags: python, numpy

Getting the below error on the code snippet that follows the error.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Pretty much brand new to using Numpy - have spent most of my time using Pandas but trying to move away from using Pandas for numerous performance related issues.

End goal is to run a LEFT JOIN on the two structed arrays.

The error seems to be prompted by the `ret[i] = tuple(row1[f1]) + tuple(row2[f1])` expression, but honestly not certain why i'd be getting this error.

Tested the `row1` and `row2` to check the number of fields vs. the `f1` which contains the dtype keys, and it all seems to line up from what I can tell.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

**ERROR**

```
ValueError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_43960/3997384146.py in <module>
     66 #            dtype=[('name', 'U10'), ('age', 'i4')])
     67 
---> 68 join_by_left(key='name', r1=struct_arr1, r2=struct_arr2, mask=True)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_43960/3997384146.py in join_by_left(key, r1, r2, mask)
     43                 print(row1[f1])
     44                 print(row2[f1])
---> 45                 ret[i] = tuple(row1[f1]) + tuple(row2[f1])
     46 
     47                 i += 1

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\numpy\ma\core.py in __setitem__(self, indx, value)
   3379         elif not self._hardmask:
   3380             # Set the data, then the mask
-> 3381             _data[indx] = dval
   3382             _mask[indx] = mval
   3383         elif hasattr(indx, 'dtype') and (indx.dtype == MaskType):

ValueError: could not assign tuple of length 6 to structure with 3 fields.
```

**FULL CODE**

```
import numpy as np

def join_by_left(key, r1, r2, mask=True):
    # figure out the dtype of the result array
    descr1 = r1.dtype.descr
    descr2 = [d for d in r2.dtype.descr if d[0] not in r1.dtype.names]
    descrm = descr1 + descr2 

    # figure out the fields we'll need from each array
    f1 = [d[0] for d in descr1]
    f2 = [d[0] for d in descr2]

    # cache the number of columns in f1
    ncol1 = len(f1)
    
    print(f1)

    # get a dict of the rows of r2 grouped by key
    rows2 = {}
    for row2 in r2:
        rows2.setdefault(row2[key], []).append(row2)

    # figure out how many rows will be in the result
    nrowm = 0
    for k1 in r1[key]:
        if k1 in rows2:
            nrowm += len(rows2[k1])
        else:
            nrowm += 1

    # allocate the return array
    _ret = np.recarray(nrowm, dtype=descrm)
    if mask:
        ret = np.ma.array(_ret, mask=True)
    else:
        ret = _ret

    # merge the data into the return array
    i = 0
    for row1 in r1:
        if row1[key] in rows2:
            for row2 in rows2[row1[key]]:
                print(row1[f1])
                print(row2[f1])
                ret[i] = tuple(row1[f1]) + tuple(row2[f1])

                i += 1
        else:
            for j in range(ncol1):
                ret[i][j] = row1[j]
            i += 1

    return ret


struct_arr1 = np.array([('jason', 28, 'j@j.com'), ('jared', 31, 'jm@j.com')],
           dtype=[('name', 'U10'), ('age', 'i4'), ('email', 'U10')])

struct_arr2 = np.array([('jason', 22, 'jm@j.com'), ('jason', 27, 'jmm@j.com'), ('george', 28, 'gmm@j.com'), ('jared', 22, 'm@j.com')],
           dtype=[('name', 'U10'), ('age', 'i4'), ('email', 'U10')])


join_by_left(key='name', r1=struct_arr1, r2=struct_arr2, mask=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the line where you're getting the error:

```
ret[i] = tuple(row1[f1]) + tuple(row2[f1])
```

The `+` operator concatenates two tuples together, so you the result is a tuple with 6 elements, not 3 with the elements added pairwise (if that is what you were expecting).

Simple example:

```
tuple('abc') + tuple('def')
```

Results in:

```
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
```